# Packaging other projects with GAE

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am trying to convert what I am doing with a standard servlet into Google App Engine. This is in separate projects, relying on a single core, which is also seperate. I cannot seem to figure out how to package the core with my GAE; the option I used before is not there. Any help would be appreciated, I included screenshots below (and I am getting class definition missing exceptions when I run the GAE version). Clearly, I could just export it as a jar and then import it, but that is a really poor solution.

This is what I did before (and this works!): https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTN2T.png

This is what I see when I try to do that with GAE (the option is missing!) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs6qD.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my JSF-GAE projects I add additional libraries to the folder `war/WEB-INF/lib` and they are deployed (with the Eclipse GAE plugin) to the App Engine.

Comment: This is only for static libraries. I want it to package another project when I deploy.

Comment: @jon Ahh, ok. I'm using Maven (but since I haven't the maven-gae plugin running) and copy the artifacts of my other required projects manually in this folder.